# What is Error SQL71578 related to Full-text Index in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12?

Tags: full-text-search, azure-sql-database, fulltext-index

When I try to compile a database project in Visual Studio targeting Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12, on the following command

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
        ([Col01] LANGUAGE 1033 STATISTICAL_SEMANTICS
       , [Col02] LANGUAGE 1033 STATISTICAL_SEMANTICS)
    KEY INDEX PK_MyTable 
    ON [MyCatalog] WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```

, I receive this error:

> Error:  SQL71578: The element Full-text Index on {table} has property IsPartOfStatisticalSemanticAnalysis set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12

What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that SQL Azure does not support `Semantic search`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features

So:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
        ([Col01]
       , [Col02])
    KEY INDEX PK_MyTable 
    ON [MyCatalog] WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```